# Using Resource Dictionaries in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I was wondering how Resource Dictionaries are to be used in with the new .NET Standard. I would like to know how we can put a Resource Dicitonary in a .NET Standard Class library as was done in the classic .Net Framework class libraries and WPF.

To clarify in the classic .NET Framework we'd have a Resource Dictionary let's call it styles.xaml in a class library so it could be consumed in multiple applications.

```xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The snippet below would then be referenced in the WPF app's app.xaml file somewhat like this.

```xaml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

So I'm looking for the equivalent way to acheive this in the new .NET Standard. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the BuildAction of your Styles.xaml in the .NET Standard ?

Comment: I didn't think to look at that. The build action is by default set to page just like it is with WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the path which might not be good.
I've made a simple project to try and see if it worked.
Using the pack kind of URI throw a compile error : the file can't be found.
But if I try with an absolute path, it works fine with both StaticResource and DynamicResource. (It should work with relative path too).

As far as I remember, it can makes sense to the why I couldn't use some Telerik styles with the `pack` URI kind of path and had to use relative path for those styles whereas I could still use pack for classical .NET project. (I may be wrong on this, it's just an observation based on this proof of concept project)

(I've tried with build action set to Page or Embedded Resource, it worked with both so it may not be that)

See below.

[image: Working proof of concept]

Comment: I notice you still have the warning highlight under the Resource Dictionary and the child elements in Styles.xaml but it still did compile and run successfully from the looks of it. Is that the case?

To clarify the reason I'm doing this is so the styles can be consumed by a WPF Client app and Server app. I'm using .NET Standard so I can hopefully even get these resources to be used on Android and iOS clients as well even if I have to write something for that it'd be worth the effort to me.

Comment: I'm going to try that in a few minutes here. I hope my clarification paints a better picture of what I'm doing here too. Even if I have to come up with a different means for mobile this is still very much needed for the Windows Desktop apps and I'd love to just have it stored in a .NET Standard library.

Comment: I do believe a relative path is going to be needed here. I could see how the pack URI could be an issue here. Hopefully it's just due to the immaturity of .NET Standard.

Comment: This does seem to work but I fear the absolute path will cause problems when this is deployed to another machine. I've been trying to do something with a relative path that doesn't involve a Pack Uri but no luck yet. Still scratching my head on that part.

Comment: I'll try to see for relative path.
Except colors, you won't share anything between Android/iOS and WPF. If you use Xamarin Forms, it's not the same component (even some get the same name like Grid).
I understand you : I too created a .NET Standard project for this. But because of limitations, my team rollback on classical project library for WPF. And so far, no regret. What's the point of making that painful with less possibility except feeling food about using .NET Standard ? :)

Comment: Yeah, my team ended up coming to the exact same conclusion with .NET Standard. We're most likely going to just have to roll back to classic .NET Framework as well. The limitations just present far too many problems for it to be worth it. I was hoping I was just missing something but it appears that is not the case.